# Azure framework 4.6 and Infragistics

Tags: c#, azure, frameworks, infragistics

The web application we use Infragistics, use the pagination of WebDataGrid control, however it stopped working two weeks ago. Infragistics send consultation and tell us that the problem is in the framework 4.6.

We recommend lowering the Azure framework version 4.5 but I do not know if this viable.

Here's the response from Infragistics technician:

> I have just tested the scenario that you've described. The issue is because there is a bug in .NET 4.6 framework, and it is expected to be fixed and released. If you want you can change your .net version (in the azure account) to a lower version. For example the issue does not exist in 4.5.

As I can resolve this point? Thank you

Comment: I would be interested to know what are the technical details of this 'bug'

Comment: Need to know if I can change the version of the framework of azure from the account of azure, pass it from 4.6 to 4.5 to test whether webdatagrid paging functions according to recomedacion infragistic technician. Right now only 3.5 or 4.6 options appear. Thanks